# User registration after facebook / openid login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, openid

I have a website where users can publish an add after they are logged in. I want to implement OpenId and Facebook Login and I was thinking to do it like this : 
- once a user is authenticated i will automatically create an account on my site using their name and email ( the ones i got from facebook/openid response).I think this is mandatory since I need an user_id in order to save their add into database. 
- next time they login i check if they have already a generated account and logged them in if is the case.

The above logic worked for OpenId(Google and Yahoo) since they return a openid_identity which seems unique for each user and can be used as password. But i don't have such data on Facebook $facebook->api('/me','GET'); . This may me think i'm not doing thing in the right way.

So, What is the best solution for adding OpenId and Facebook in this case ? If this is a correct way what can i use as password for Facebook generate accounts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Oauth2, since there is no OpenID provider at facebook. You may use user id provided by $facebook->api('/me','GET'); which is always linked to particular user. And later you re-ask it at each fb login to compare with stored data.

Comment: yes the user id is unique but in the same time is a public data and doesn't look like a thing you can use as pass. Somebody may guess this approach and hijack the accounts

Comment: If this data was sent by FB server you may trust it.

Comment: Oauth and OpenID are slightly different things. OpenID is Authentication protocol which just says "yes this is user %username%". Oauth is authorization protocol which allows you access users data at remotr server like FB. So if you call ->me() it is equivalent to user called this method at FB homepage. But you do it in under the hood between servers, without user interaction.